# how can i add multiple actions for one Button

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button, countdown

i try to add play and pause action in one button
this is my code i just add play action, can you help me, please?

```
 fab_play_pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            timerHasStarted = true;
            countDownTimer.start();


            Resources res = getResources();
            Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_progressbar_drawable);
            final ProgressBar mProgress = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.circularProgressbar);
            mProgress.setProgress(0);   // Main Progress
            mProgress.setSecondaryProgress(100); // Secondary Progress
            mProgress.setMax(100); // Maximum Progress
            mProgress.setProgressDrawable(drawable);
            mProgress.setRotation(0);

            ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mProgress, "progress", 0, 100);
            animation.setDuration(startTime);
            animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
            animation.start();

        }
    });
```

Comment: keep a boolean check your state and perform the action regarding the state using a simple if else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it by this:

set it **default to Play**

```
    fab_play_pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
             String text = btnAdd.getText().toString();

               if(text.equalsIgnoreCase("Play")){
                  //your code
                   fab_play_pause.setText("pause")
               }
              else if(text.equalsIgnoreCase("pause"))
               {
                  //your code
                  fab_play_pause.setText("Play")
               }
            }
        });
```

For Drawble :

```
 fab_play_pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                int resId = (Integer) view.getTag();

                   if(resId == R.drawable.play){
                      //your code
                      //change background for pause
                   }
                  else if(resId == R.drawable.pause)
                   {
                      //your code
                      //change background for play
                   }
                }
            });
```

Comment: `==`  --> `equals`

Comment: I'd rather see the button reacting to a boolean state variable than something that's already a reaction to state (text or drawable in the UI)...

Answer (score 0):

solution

```
private static final String PLAY_ICON = "playIcon";
    private static final String PAUSE_ICON = "pauseImage";

    fab_play_pause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_white_24dp);
    fab_play_pause.setTag(PLAY_ICON);
    fab_play_pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String tag = (String) view.getTag();

            if (view.getTag() == PLAY_ICON){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "play",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                fab_play_pause.setTag(PAUSE_ICON);
            }else if (view.getTag() == PAUSE_ICON){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "pause",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    });
```